# Update page view

Tags: php, mysql

Im create this code to store page view in database, but i have problem to update row now...

I need to check if session and url is same than i need update row view.. here is code

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$browser = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$referer = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$session = session_id();


mysql_query("   INSERT INTO page_view(ip,url,referer,session,view) 
                    VALUES (
                    '".$ip."',
                    '".$url."',
                    '".$referer."',
                    '".$session."',
                    '1')
                    ");
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but is there a reason why you wouldn't want to check on the IP address as well? I'm just thinking that [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) would go undetected if you just update the `view` column without checking that it came from the same IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `url,session` pair unique and use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO page_view(ip,url,referer,session,view) 
                VALUES (
                '".$ip."',
                '".$url."',
                '".$referer."',
                '".$session."',
                '1')
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE view = view +1
                ");
```

Comment: Because sessionids are reused, it is possible another user from another IP could be assigned the same sessionid, so I would include the IP in the unique key as well.

Comment: It's not good idea, now session is unique also and url and when u go to other url there is no new record in database simple will be updated first one because session is same...

Comment: @DraganA. Session_id must be unique means not as column index in mysql. I mean as a php session must be unique to user. And in mysql table `session, url` is unique as a pair. There is no need to add ip as uniq

Comment: @safarov sessions are concurrently unique, not permanently unique. When I go to a web site, the site generates a random session id, and checks it against the list of currently active ids to ensure it is not currently in use. There is no history maintained (generally) of past session ids. It is possible (albeit not necessarily likely on a small site) for a future user to be assigned the same session id.

Comment: @wige that very low probablity that expired session overload. So ip addresses also dynamic. But yes, you can add `ip, session, url` as uniq to be more sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would query the last insert for that session, then check if the url changed.

```
If (changed) update;
Else insert;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a unique index on the columns ip, url and session, then do an insert... on duplicate key:

```
INSERT INTO page_view(ip,url,referer,session,view)
VALUES ('".$ip."','".$url."','".referer."','".$session."','1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE view = view + '1'");
```